# select elements from different html files linked to the same js file

Tags: javascript

I got two different html files, every file has a button BTN 1 and BTN 2, linked to the same js file, so when I click one of the buttons I need to insert a class to change the background color of both pages, how could I select both buttons with js to do this.

I have tried to select the buttons like this:

var ccc = document.getElementsByClassName("hola");
console.log(ccc);

but I get this:

HTMLCollection [button.hola]
length: 1
0: button.hola
**proto**: HTMLCollection

Just one button. if I insert a class when click it changes only the body of that page,  but I need to change both no matter what buttom i click on.

How could I do this

Thanks for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="hello">BTN 1</button>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="hello">BTN 2</button>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: hmm... is this the new HTML? first time I see two HTML in one HTML

Comment: What is the problem, specifically? You would have to `open()` *(bad idea)*  the other page in another window, or put your other page in an `<iframe>`. You get the iframe window with `const otherWindow = iframeElement.contentWindow, otherDoc = otherWindow.document;`.  You have to have CORS access either way. You should know that this will not have an effect on the website itself, just the Client.

Comment: Hello, no no , html files are independent but both are linked to the same js file, i need to slect both button in js

Comment: So, you just pretend to recycle the Javascript file between two HTML's? That's no problem. If you are pretending to link those HTML's by one script, you can. Each HTML will have their own script (a copy of it). This behavior you want should be solved by a server where different clients point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="hello">BTN 1</button>

  <script>
       var ccc = document.querySelector("button#hello")

       ccc.addEventListener('click', function() {
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: run the script twice so you can see it

Comment: not really, in your code both buttons are in the same page, but in my code there are two  buttons with the same class in diffetent pages page1 and page 2, I need to change the color of body of both pages no matter  if i click the button of page one or page two using the saame js file

Comment: just copy and paste that code on both files and it will work

Comment: liek this  <script src="js/script.js"></script> in both pages

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is probably with the selection. When you use `getElementsByClassName` you are getting an array of elements, not a single element. So if you will use `document.getElementsByClassName("hola")[0]` you will get your element.

I think you should use `id` instead of `className`, because when you use `document.getElementsByClassName("abc")` you're getting an array of elements of the same class. Since you're using it in 2 different pages, and maybe use the same class for other elements too, the array's order can be different and will make it hard to find your button.

Use `document.getElementById("someID")` to get a specific element, and just use the same `id` for both buttons (since they are on different pages it shouldn't be a problem).

```js
let button = document.getElementById("myRedBodyButton");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.add("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<button id="myRedBodyButton">clickMe</button>
```